# Type-safe way to divide a tuple into multiple tuples

Tags: scala, generics, tuples

We have a trait that among other things contains an `execute[T <: Record](Seq[(Session) => T]): Seq[T]` method, where `Record` is the supertrait of all traits that we're retrieving from the database

```
trait DbTrait {
  val threadCount: Int
  val db: Database
  protected def getGroupSize(size: Int, threadCount: Int) {
    (size / threadCount) + if(size % threadCount == 0) 0 else 1
  }
  def execute[T <: Record](funs: Seq[(Session) => T]): Seq[T]
}

trait DbTraitSingle extends DbTrait {
  val threadCount = 1
  def execute[T <: Record](funs: Seq[(Session) => T]): Seq[T] =
    db.withSession{session: Session => funs.map(f => f(session))}
}

trait DbTraitMulti extends DbTrait {
  val threadCount = 4
  def execute[T <: Record](funs: Seq[(Session) => T): Seq[T] =
    funs.grouped(getGroupSize(funs.size, threadCount)).map(funs => Future {
      db.withSession{session: Session => funs.map(f => f(session))}
    }.toList.flatten
}
```

and so on.  Ideally we'd like to be able to create something like a

```
def executePoly2[T1 <: Record, T2 <: Record]
  (tuple: Tuple2[(Session) => T1, (Session) => T2]): Tuple2[T1, T2]
```

for arbitrary tuples (i.e. an executePoly3, executePoly4, etc), but there are two problems:

1. Is there a way to reduce the amount of boilerplate here, or would we be stuck creating 22 different method signatures?
2. Is there a type-safe way to split up a tuple similar to the `seq.grouped` method call, or are we stuck having special cases for all of the different `threadCount` values (which at present doesn't exceed 4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get to something very easy to use using the Shapeless library by Miles Sabin. See what they can do with a [Tuple](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview%3a-shapeless-2.0.0#hlist-style-operations-on-standard-scala-tuples). Specifically abstracting over arity.

```
 import syntax.std.tuple._
 import poly._

 var myProducedTuple = myTuple map (_(session))
```

Comment: Thanks wheaties, sorry for my ignorance but I'm a bit confused by the shapeless syntax - it looks like I need to convert my tuple to an HList, apply a polymorphic map function, and convert the resulting HList back into a tuple (or rely on my callers to do the HList conversions for me).  However, the example polymorphic functions are of the form e.g. `Set ~> Option`, whereas I'd need something like `Session ~> T` with `Session` as an invariant type, but I'm having trouble finding an example of a polymorphic function with a naked `T` in it - they're all wrapped in an `Option` or `Set` etc