# Creating a shapeless polymorphic function with a naked type param

Tags: scala, polymorphism, shapeless

As described here

[Type-safe way to divide a tuple into multiple tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22411368/type-safe-way-to-divide-a-tuple-into-multiple-tuples)

I have a method with the following signature

```
def execute[T <: Record](funs: Seq[(Session) => T]): Seq[T]
```

where `Session` is a [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/) database session; the basic implementation of this method is

```
def execute[T <: Record](funs: Seq[(Session) => T): Seq[T] = {
  db withSession { 
    session: Session => funs.map(fun => fun(session))
}}
```

(where `db` is a Slick `Database`) with other implementations that add things like logging, caching, multi-threading, etc.  In particular, the multi-threading implementation uses `funs.grouped(ceil(funs.size / threadCount)).map(funs => Future {})` to divide up the functions among several threads.

I would like to create a version of the method that accepts a tuple of functions so that I can return values of different types - as described in the question linked to above I didn't know of a good way to split up a tuple into smaller tuples and then recombine the results for the multi-threaded case, but the answer to that question was to use the [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) library's `HList`s - however I am unclear as to how I can create a polymorphic variant of the `(Session) => T` function, the problem being that all of the examples of polymorphic functions that I've seen use wrapped type params, e.g. `(Set ~> Option)` which each wrap a polymorphic `T`, but I am trying to create a `(Session ~> T)` function where `Session` is invariant and the polymorphic `T` isn't wrapped in a `Set` or `Option` etc.  I am doubtless looking at this problem the wrong way owing to not having sufficient experience with Shapeless.

How can I use Shapeless to create a polymorphic version of the `def execute(funs: Seq[(Session) => T]): Seq[T]` function?

Comment: What's the return type of `execute` here when you remove the `ToList`? There are other ways to enforce the constraint, but I'm not sure why this one isn't working.

Comment: @TravisBrown My mistake, I forgot that the database returns Option[Record]; if I change the parameter to ToList[0, Option[Record]] then it works just fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually don't really need or want a polymorphic function here—you can get what you're looking for from a few type classes that Shapeless provides out of the box. It looks a little odd, but it's not really all that complicated (note that I'm using Shapeless 2.0—you could do this in 1.2.4, but it'd be messier):

```
import shapeless._, ops.tuple.{ ConstMapper, ToList, ZipApply }
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._

def execute[F <: Product, S, O](funs: F)(implicit
  cm: ConstMapper.Aux[F, Session, S],
  za: ZipApply.Aux[F, S, O],
  tl: ToList[O, Record]
): O = db withSession { session: Session =>
  funs.zipApply(funs.mapConst(session))
}
```

We're essentially just taking our session, making a new tuple by repeating it as many times as our input is long, zipping the input tuple with this new tuple of sessions, and then applying the first part of each zipped element to the second part. The `ToList` part requires all elements of the resulting tuple to be subtypes of `Record`.

For the sake of a complete working example, here are some simple demonstration definitions:

```
type Session = String
trait Record
case class RecordX(s: String) extends Record
case class RecordY(i: Int) extends Record

def x(s: Session) = RecordX(s)
def y(s: Session) = RecordY(s.size)

object db {
  def withSession[T](f: Session => T) = f("foo")
}
```

And it works!

```
scala> execute((x _, y _))
res0: (RecordX, RecordY) = (RecordX(foo),RecordY(3))
```

We get a nice appropriately statically typed tuple as our result.

Comment: Thanks, your example works if I remove the ToList param; with the param included I get the compiler error "could not find implicit value for parameter tl: shapeless.ops.tuple.ToList[O,Record]"; I'm duplicating your code except that I've replaced your stubbed `Record` and `withSession` with actual `Record` instances and database calls; I'm editing my question with the code I used.

Comment: As a side note, and as Cody Allen points out [here](https://twitter.com/FouriersTrick/status/449192032490512384), this looks a lot like sequencing the `HList` through the reader monad. The Typelevel project [does provide](https://github.com/typelevel/shapeless-contrib) a `sequence` for `HList`s, but it's kind of touchy and still needs some work—getting it to work here would not be trivial. You can see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16128064/334519) for more detail about sequencing `HList`s, but for now you're probably best off with the approach here.

Comment: As a side note to the side note, if you import scalaz.std.function._ you get the type class instances necessary to do this with raw functions without the need to wrap them in Reader.